# Isomorphic Submodules implies Isomorphic Quotients?

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, free-modules

I am trying to solve this exercise in the Book of Roman: if $S$ and $T$ are isomorphic submodules of a module $M$ it does
not necessarily follow that  $M/S\approx M/T$. Prove that this statement does hold if all modules are free and have finite rank.

I have a counterexample but not a proof.

Comment: Since you are already given that $M/S$ and $M/T$ are free, all you have to prove is that their ranks are the same.  Now prove this statement: rank($S)+$rank$(M/S)=$rank$(M)$.

Comment: I am undecided if I also consider the quotients as free modules of finite range. If so, then it is very easy.

Comment: You have to, because otherwise the statement isn't true: Say $R=M = \mathbb{Z}$ and $S=M$ and $T=2M$.

Comment: I see. Thanks for all.

Comment: One of the two of you should post an answer to resolve this post.

Answer (score 0):

We have   $\textrm{rank}\left(M\right)=\textrm{rank}\left(S\right)+\textrm{rank}\left(M/S\right)$ and $\textrm{rank}\left(M\right)=\textrm{rank}\left(T\right)+\textrm{rank}\left(M/T\right)$.
Since $S\approx T$  then  $\textrm{rank}\left(M/S\right)=\textrm{rank}\left(M/T\right)$ . Therefore $M/S\approx M/T$ .